# Overwrite default Content-Type when using saveparameters in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using the **saveRow** function in **inline_editing** in jqGrid, the default Content-Type is "**application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8**" with the following

```
saveparameters = {
    "successfunc" : null,
    "url" : myUrl,
        "extraparam" : {},
    "aftersavefunc" : null,
    "errorfunc": null,
    "afterrestorefunc" : null,
    "restoreAfterError" : true,
    "mtype" : "POST"
}

jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('saveRow',rowid,  saveparameters);
```

I want to overwrite the Content-Type to "**application/json; charset=utf-8**", so I can have the successfunc like

```
successfunc : function(response){
    //parse the json response
}
```

Is this possible and how to overwrite it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately the grid does not allow you to specify the `contentType` option in this particular calls to [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - you can see it yourself in the source code to [`grid.inlinedit.js`](https://github.com/justinethier/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L261). Thus it uses the default content type as you noted in your question.

But maybe that's OK. It seems like what you really want is to receive JSON data, in which case the format of the data sent to the server does not matter. The reponse format is controlled by the `dataType` option, which also cannot be specified in the jqGrid API. However, it is inferred based upon the MIME type from your server's response:

> Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)
>   The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

So just make sure you set the MIME type in your response to `application/json; charset=utf-8` and you should be good.